# My question is about weird behavior of boot manager after installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I recently installed Ubuntu by freeing some space from I hard disk. It is working fine without any issues. But i see this weird behavior in boot manager. Every time i start ubuntu a new link is generating.

[image]